# Google Maps for Business crashing app with R$styleable NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-maps

Converting one of my apps over to use the new Google Maps for Business package and now I am stuck with a crash every time our activity attempts to call setContentView() in our onCreate() method.

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // external dependencies: will need network connection if not already cached
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

    // local dependencies: jar libraries checked into source control
    compile files('libs/resty-0.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-1.4.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/robospice-cache-1.4.9.jar')
    compile files ('libs/maps_m4b-2.12.0.rc1.jar')
}
```

activity_location.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.m4b.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Crash:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/m4b/maps/R$styleable;
            at com.google.android.m4b.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(GoogleMapOptions.java:428)
            at com.google.android.m4b.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(MapFragment.java:408)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2115)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.nate.android.hammerhead.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:106)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.m4b.maps.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nate.android.hammerhead-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.google.android.m4b.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(GoogleMapOptions.java:428)
            at com.google.android.m4b.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(MapFragment.java:408)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2115)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5282)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
            at com.nate.android.hammerhead.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:106)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.m4b.maps.R$styleable
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 28 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I have followed the guide provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/) and what should have been a simple swap for the new static jar library has turned into a configuration nightmare trying to track this down to little or no avail.

Comment: From the documentation, `you should remove any references to the com.google.android.gms.maps package. If you make use of Play services within your app to use other Google APIs, please ensure that you use only the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work (the com.google.android.m4b.maps package) to access Maps.`

Comment: I already have removed any and all references to the com.google.android.gms.maps package. The reason that I still include the play services is because I need that dependency for Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with a Google representative it appears that this was an issue with the *.jar package for the current 2.12.0.rc1 version.

Answer (score 0):

How did you import the jar file?

First you need to unzip the downloaded zip file, and copy the Jar files from the `google-maps-sdk-m4b_lib -> libs` folder to Android Studio's libs folder.

See the below image for the completed Jar files path:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I pulled them into my projects libs directory and then compile them with Gradle in the dependencies section of the build.gradle file. They are definitely being pulled into my project since I can reference them in my import statements.

Comment: I didnt see `guava-jdk4-14.0.1.jar` in your grade statements. Also did you change the name of `maps_m4b.jar` to `maps_m4b-2.12.0.rc1.jar`, you should use the original name `maps_m4b.jar` instead. In addition, you can do `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` in your grade dependencies, so you can make sure it import all necessary files.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to help, but unfortunately the guava-jdk being included doesn't have any effect on the problem given the R$styleable that the error is creating is part of the com.google.android.m4b.maps package.

Comment: Have you tried to unzip your com.google.android.m4b jar, see if you can find `GoogleMapOptions` class file.

Comment: Yah, I have validated that the expected class files are there and I can import and reference them without problems in Android Studio.